# Add toolbar item to default toolbar

Tags: tinymce-4

I just want to add an item to default tinymce config, something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: "customimageupload",
  toolbar: tinymce_default_toolbar + " customimageupload"
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to set the toolbar based on the "default" toolbar.  If you use the `toolbar` setting you need to explicitly mention all the items you want.  From looking at the source code of the editor the default toolbar is:

```
var defaultToolbar = "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft" 
                   + "aligncenter alignright alignjustify | " 
                   + "bullist numlist outdent indent | link image";
```

Do note that at least some of these options would need a plugin loaded before they appear (e.g. the list related buttons).

For future reference this information on the default toolbar is found in the following file:  `tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js`